# Align button right in CSS bootstrap moves to under brand when screen width decreases

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am using bootstrap and in the nav bar I have a button like so:

```
{% block navbar %}
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">My amazing site</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Button code -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <input class="tgl tgl-skewed" id="cb3" type="checkbox"/>
      <label class="tgl-btn" data-tg-off="$" data-tg-on="฿" for="cb3"></label>
    </ul>
    <!-- Button code -->
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The button is right aligned as desired however it jumps to under the brand title when the screen width decreases (e.g. mobile). How can I make it always stick right and not move to below the brand? Any pointers on how to do this would be great! Thanks

EDIT CSS:

```
.tg-list {
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tg-list-item {
  margin: 0 2em;
}

.tgl {
  display: none;
}
.tgl, .tgl:after, .tgl:before, .tgl *, .tgl *:after, .tgl *:before, .tgl + .tgl-btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 12px;
}
.tgl::-moz-selection, .tgl:after::-moz-selection, .tgl:before::-moz-selection, .tgl *::-moz-selection, .tgl *:after::-moz-selection, .tgl *:before::-moz-selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::-moz-selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl::selection, .tgl:after::selection, .tgl:before::selection, .tgl *::selection, .tgl *:after::selection, .tgl *:before::selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}
.tgl:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
          transform: skew(-10deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #888;
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:before {
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
          transform: skew(10deg);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 100%;
  content: attr(data-tg-on);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:before {
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-tg-off);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:active {
  background: #888;
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:active:before {
  left: -10%;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #58BE23;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:before {
  left: -100%;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  left: 10%;
}
```

Image of the behaviour:

[image]

Comment: can you add a jfiddle?

Comment: you could set the position as `absolute `and `right:0px`

Comment: what's the width of the div to the left of the button?

Comment: Why you dont use "navbar-collapse collapse" for mobile screen ?

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior updated my question

Comment: @Avihaym I don't want a collapse menu I just want the button to stick to the right. I have updated my question.

Comment: @DCR updated my question.

Comment: @M0ns1f tried that and no change.

Comment: The problem may be the `display:inline-block` try using `display:inline-flex`, but did you set the parent div position as relative !?